# Show/hide textfile depending on radio buttons' selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this is a repeated question, but I cannot make it run. I tried all the solutions I found here in SO and googling...

I have this radio button form in my page. What I want is that when the user selects the '*only one attendee*' option a text field appears ONLY for this option. If the user selects another one it dissapears.

[image: Normal form]

Once the user selects *only one* option, the text box appears.

[image: expanded form]

I've been trying doing with javascript. I use this piece of code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        $("#send_to_one").hide();
        $("input:radio[name="people"]").change(function(){  
          if(this.checked){
            if(this.value =='one'){
              $("#send_to_one").show()
            }else{
              $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }
         }
    }
  });
</script>
```

The form's code is

```
  <div id="send_to">
    <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="all" checked="checked">all the attendees</br>      
    <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="one" >only one attendee<br/>
    <div id="send_to_one">
      <label>Write the attendee's name: </label><input type="text" id="attendeename"><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="group">a group of attendees</br>              
  </div>
```

I've checked that the javascript files are loaded. I also tried putting the javascript code inside the html.erb file where the form is, in a separated .js file and in application.htm.erb's `<head></head>` section, but no luck. **Where do I need to put each part of code exactly in order to work?**

Using Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.8.9. I'm also using JQuery

Comment: (OT) `</br>` != `<br />` and `<input>` != `<input />`

Comment: off the top of my head: `$("input:radio[name="people"]").` should be `$("input:radio[name='people']").`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/umefaz/2/edit)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div id="send_to">
  <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="all" checked="checked" />all the attendees<br/>      
  <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="one" />only one attendee<br/>
  <div id="send_to_one">
      <label>Write the attendee's name: </label><input type="text" id="attendeename" /><br/><br/>
  </div>
  <input type="radio" id="send_poll" name="people" value="group" />a group of attendees<br/>              
</div>
```

jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#send_to_one").hide();

    $("input:radio[name='people']").change(function(){  

            if(this.value == 'one' && this.checked){
              $("#send_to_one").show();
            }else{
              $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send_to_one").hide();
    $("input:radio[name='people']").change(function(){  
         if(this.checked){
            if(this.value =='one'){
              $("#send_to_one").show()
            }else{
              $("#send_to_one").hide();
            }
         } 
    });
});
```

Your code was right, but a few missing braces, brackets, and unescaped quotes. Are you using any form of smart javascript editor? Because you really should...

http://jsfiddle.net/7yt2A/